# How to create a progress bar using css and based on current width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have just started my journey with `javascript` and I am trying to find a solution for a problem.

I created a div that is a progress bar that will gradually fill the full width of the div as we press the button. Default width of the button should start as 0% and go up to 100%.  I am trying to come up with `jQuery` or a vanilla `javascript` but I am unable to do this. Any help would be great as I am really interested in improving my `jQuery/JS` skills.

```
<div id="myProgress">
    <div id="progressbar"></div>
    <button id="button-progress"></button>
</div>
```

```
#myProgress {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ddd;
}

#progressbar {
    width: 0%;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #1D1387;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: how do you decide  when to increase the progress? what is the progress reflecting?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

```js
var i = 0;
function move() {
  if (i == 0) {
    i = 1;
    var elem = document.getElementById("myBar"); //get element
    var width = 10; //Set value
    var id = setInterval(frame, 10); // set the time interval
    function frame() {
      if (width >= 100) {
        clearInterval(id); //If width is already 100% clear interval
        i = 0;//reset to counter
      } else {
        width++;
        elem.style.width = width + "%"; //Update the style
        elem.innerHTML = width  + "%"; //Update the counter
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
<style>
#myProgress {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#myBar {
  width: 10%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="myBar">10%</div>
</div>

<br>
<button onclick="move()">Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery animate function. Utilizing step option will give the current progress of the animation. Use that to update counter. Also, you can control the duration using the duration option.

```js
jQuery("#button-progress").on("click", function() {
  jQuery("#progressbar").animate({
    width: "100%"
  }, {
    // The entire duration of the animation
    duration: 2000,
    // Runs every step of the animation
    step: function(number) {
      let current = Math.floor(number);
      jQuery(this).text(current + "%");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#myProgress {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#progressbar {
  width: 0%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #1D1387;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="progressbar">0%</div>
</div>
<br><br>
<button id="button-progress">Animate !</button>
```