# progress bar increases as we press the button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am new to programming but trying to solve a problem. 
I am trying to increase a progress bar as I press on the "d" button. I am trying to do it recursively but I don't have enough skills to do it properly. Any help would be greately appreciated.

My js file looks like this so far:

```
window.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
    function counter(p) {
        //if the button is "d"
        if (e.keyCode === 100) {
            //target progressbar width and increase it 
            $('#progressbar').css('width', function(index, value) {

                return $("#progressbar").css('width', ((p * 2) + "%"));
            });

            if ($('#progressbar').width() < 100) {
                return counti(p + 1)
            }
        }
    };
    counti(1);
});
```

My html:

```
 <div id = "myProgress" >
   <div id = "progressbar" > 0 / 50 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: related to your old question or the same: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58889692/8620333 ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif it is a different question, similar problem but not exactly the same :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var count = 0;
var maxCount = 50;
var progressBar = document.getElementById("progressbar")

window.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {

  //if the button is "d"
  if (e.keyCode === 100) {
    // increase count if it's less than maxCount
    count = count === maxCount ? maxCount : count + 1;
    //target progressbar width and increase it
    var newWidth = (count / maxCount) * 100 + "%";
    progressBar.style.width = newWidth;
    progressBar.innerHTML = count + "/" + maxCount

  }
});
```

```css
#myProgress {
  width: 400px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #e4e4e4;
}

#progressbar {
  width: 0%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #5980a7;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="progressbar">0/50</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cool ;-)  can you flag it as answered?